# Duplicate entry mysql unique field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `'code_number'` column with varchar(25) field type, and I make it into **`Unique`** field type. I try to insert 2 number to the `number` column with different number. First number is `'112225577'` and for the second number is `'112228899'`. Now I'm trying to update the first number, and only change 3 last digit number `'577'` with `'433'`, became `'112225433'`. But I got error `Duplicate entry '112225433' for key 'code_number'`.

How can it be duplicate? I only have 2 data and the data is not same. Can anybody explain to me why this happening?

**UPDATE**

here is my code.

**Product**

```
id INT(11)
product VARCHAR(250)
code_number VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE
...
```

**Account**

```
id INT(11)
name VARCHAR(250)
email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
...
```

And my query is like this:

```
$this->db->set('code_number','112225433');
$this->db->where('code_number','112225577');
$this->db->update('product');
```

Same problem goes to email column when i try to update account record.
here is the code sample:

```
$this->db->set('email','andy123@yahoo.com');
$this->db->where('name','Andy');
$this->db->update('account');
```

the email data in email column where `name='Andy'` is `'andy123@hotmail.com'`.

Comment: Can you please post your PHP code / mySQL schema definitions

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter framework, so my query update using active records.
same problem I got when I'm trying to update email column in my account table.

check my update later.

Comment: Thanks for sharing which framework you're using.
Can you post some code, it's difficult to begin helping you if there's not more information than what's already been mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this without a problem (see the SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d09292)).

I imagine that you are doing something where *both* rows are getting updated to the same value, the equivalent of:

```
update t
    set code_number = '112225433';
```

This will generate exactly the error you report.  There are, no doubt, many SQL queries that would have this effect.  But, this would generate such an error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your SQL editor. For instance, it could show you the previous value but it could have update it already, so that you you believe that it has not been changed yet. I ever had such problem like this before: the value was updated in the DB but the editor had no updated yet.